# Toggling between specific items in a multi select JList

Tags: java, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a class that extends JList & uses the DefaultListModel.

So let's say that I have a list that contains items A, B, C, D, etc.

I am able to select multiple items, but I would like it so that A & B can never be selected at the same time. So I would like it so that if I select A then B, A gets deselected selected and vice versa.

Is this possible?

Edit: Added initial implementation

```
public TestList extends JList {
    public void TestList() {
        super(new DefaultModelList());
    }

    // Method 2
    public void addSelectionInterval(int anchor, int lead) {
        //DO Work
    }

    // Method 3
    public void setSelectedValue(Object obj, boolean shouldScroll) {
        // DO WORK
    }
}

TestList test = new TestList();
// Method 1
test.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        // check value selected and deselect if necessary
    }
}
```

I have tried these ways, but none of them seem to be working. The current issue is when I select an item, none of these get run as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a custom `ListSelectionModel` and override the `addSelectionInterval(...)` method.

The logic in this method would need to validate the item about to be selected, before you invoke `super.addSelectionInterval(...)` if the selection meets your specific requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can use the ListSelectionModel because changing would break a lot of code. Also, the addSelectionInvterval does has no way of getting the item about to be selected.

Comment: @ghost013, `I can use the ListSelectionModel because changing would break a lot of code` it would not break any code. `addSelectionInvterval does has no way of getting the item about to be selected.` what do you think the parameters represent?

Comment: I've tried your way, but is not working. From debugging, when I select an item on the list, the addSelectionInterval is not getting called as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ghost013, 1) I did not suggest to override the JList, I suggested to create a custom ListSelectionModel. 2) Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.